# SASS add important to every property in mixin

Tags: sass

Is there a way how to add !important to every property in `@mixin`?

For example:

```
@mixin myMixin {
    color:red;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
    ...
}
p {
    @include myMixin(!important);
    //or
    //@include myMixin!important; => SASS Syntax Error
}
```

this is result in css

```
p {
    color:red;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
    ...
}
```

and I want this

```
p {
    color:red!important;
    border:1px solid red!important;
    position:relative!important;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it is not recommended to use `!important` to override CSS properties, you can however use the `@each` to iterate over a map and perform the string interpolation.

```
@mixin myMixin($str){
  $prop : (
    color:red,
    border:1px solid red,
    position:relative
  );
  @each $key, $value in $prop {
    #{$key}: #{$value} #{$str};
  }
}
p{
    @include myMixin(!important);
}
```